# Searching a linked list using hash search

Tags: c, linux, hash, linked-list

I am a beginner. I have never done hash search. But now, I just have to do it.

I have a linked list containing about 3500 random integers upto 10 lakh(1000000) value. I want to search any element using hash search.

debugger is giving seg fault in the function ht_set on first if(condition) . 
Please tell me how to resolve it?
Here is my code :

```
typedef struct entry_s
{
    int key;
    int value;
    struct entry_s *next1;
} entry_t;
typedef struct hashtable_s
{
    int size;
    entry_t **table;
}hashtable_t;

int ht_hash(hashtable_t *hashtable, int key)
{
    int index;
    index=key%hashtable->size;
    return index;
}
entry_t *ht_newpair( int key, int value )
{
    entry_t *newpair;

    if((newpair = malloc( sizeof( entry_t)))== NULL || newpair->key == key || newpair->value==value)
    return NULL;
    newpair->next1 = NULL;
    return newpair;
}


void ht_set( hashtable_t *hashtable, int key, int value )
{
    int bin = 0;
    entry_t *newpair = NULL;
    entry_t *next1 = NULL;
    entry_t *last = NULL;

    bin = ht_hash(hashtable, key);
    next1 = hashtable->table[bin];
    while( next1 != NULL && key==next1->key)
    {
            last = next1;
            next1 = next1->next1;
    }

    if( next1 != NULL || key==next1->key)
     next1->value =value;
    else
    {
          newpair = ht_newpair( key, value );
          if( next1 == hashtable->table[ bin ] )
          {
                    newpair->next1 = next1;
                    hashtable->table[ bin ] = newpair;
          }
          else if ( next1 == NULL )
          last->next1 = newpair;
          else
          {
                    newpair->next1 = next1;
                    last->next1 = newpair;
          }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds interesting however risk-reward% too low to respond...

Comment: `unsigned long int hashval;
        static int i = 0;
        hashval += i;` hashval is uninitialised. (and the function makes little sense anyway)

Comment: yeah.. ok i will initialise it with some value ,say 50. Thanks. And what else??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing out on the basic idea of hashing, how it's commonly used in the [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure. Please read up on it.

Basically, hashes are not typically used when searching a linked list; the hash is used to build an index into a table (an array), to get that quick mapping of the content onto an array location.

Some hash tables resolve collisions with [*separate chaining*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining), in which each table slot is the head of a list of items that all have hashed to the same place. So, when you're searching that list, you're *not* searching by hash (remember, *all* items in the list have the same hash value) but doing full comparisons.

Comment: I have studied hash table and tried to implement it by the above code. It's giving segmentation fault. Please go through it and let me know the error. Thanks

Comment: Well, run it in a debugger and tell us *where* it seg faults, at least.

Comment: debugger is giving seg fault in the function ht_set on first if(condition)